# Iteration and modification of array best approach

Tags: php, php-5.3

The following is the best way to **iterate through and modify** array in PHP5.*+

<sup>(source: http://zend-php.appspot.com/questions_list  -- question #3)</sup>

```
$array = array("one" => 1, "two" => 2, "three" => 3, "four" => 4, "five" => 5);
foreach($array as $key => &$val) {
   $val += 1;
}
```

What is it about this method of **iterating and modifying** that makes it better than others?

Can someone please explain how come this actually works?

This iterates just fine, why include `as $key => &$val` if we are not using the keys?, also why do we need to include the `&` in `&$val`:

```
foreach($array as $val){
   echo $val;
}
```

I appreciate the explanation,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give a source for your claim?

Comment: http://zend-php.appspot.com/questions_list ...Question #3

Comment: It says _best_, not _fastest_!

Comment: I apologize for the typo, please see edited.

Comment: Why the down vote? how is this a bad question?

Comment: You probably overlooked that the question didn't ask for "best" in such an unqualified manner as your question here. It also contains a subtle hint in "iterate and **modify**".

Comment: The & indicates that $val is a pointer and & is the memory location of it. At least thats how C is..

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with it from `C` as well, however, I didn't see the use for it in the foreach loop.

Comment: @dudemanbearpig C pointers and PHP references are not the same thing. Related concepts, but very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they intend to *modify* the value, getting it as a reference is clever.

```
$array = array("one" => 1, "two" => 2, "three" => 3, "four" => 4, "five" => 5);
foreach($array as $key => &$val) {
   $val += 1;
}
```

Will add `1` to all values.

If you did:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
   $val += 1;
}
```

Nothing would happen.

I strongly disagree that it is the *best* way though. I much prefer to see:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
   $array[$key] += 1;
}
```

because it's much more straightforward. I'll gladly believe it doesn't perform as well, but I also don't care (unless there is a reason to start optimizing).

It's also worth mentioning that using references can lead to strange situations, such as: [PHP reference causes data corruption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19593835/php-reference-causes-data-corruption)

*PS. I didn't downvote. I'm getting really annoyed by people downvoting and not leaving a comment.*

Comment: In some programming languages - C# and Java (I think) you can not modify the elements that you get using foreach. From this answer it seems that in PHP you could do that, so maybe that's the reason behind `$key => $val`.

Comment: `foreach($array as $key => $val) {
   $val += 1;
} ` **does** modify the values! Please edit!

Comment: Just tested it, using your '**proof**'. It modifies `$val` values within the scope of the `foreach` loop, so something **does** happen. Obviously the values are lost outside of the loop, if that's what you mean by 'nothing happens'.

Comment: I'd say that `$array[$key] += 1` is more error prone when you're renaming the `$array` variable. Reducing the redundancy and thereby coupling of code by using a reference is ever so slightly more reliable in this scenario and hence preferably, IMHO. It also expresses the intention better, IMHO.

Comment: Maybe the OP misses the `&` in `foreach($array as $key => &$val)` which i think makes it possible to manipulate the data. Is that right?

Comment: deceze there is no such concern if you use variable renaming / refactoring macros that all modern IDEs have. - @Leron, yes, it causes the value to be passed as a reference. AnchovyLegend, yes that is what I meant, the changes don't persist outside of the loop.

Comment: Well, in this case I think that `foreach` should be used only to display data. Even though passing by reference do the trick it seems a little bit like a hack to me and also, I think there's a good reason `foreach` to be implemented like this. So maybe that's part of the answer - `foreach` is optimized for displaying data and no manipulating (though I'm not sure that's the case).

Comment: Isn't this more optimal, since we are not using the keys anyways? 
`foreach($array as &$val) {
      $val += 1;
    }`

**note:** it modifies that actual array value outside the scope of the array.

Comment: Sure, if you don't need the key in your loop this is probably even better. This does show you how trivial Zend certification is though. I don't believe there is a single best solution because what the best solution is may change over time. I'd rather ask about the reasoning, which is a much more valuable skill to have.

Answer (score 1):

The question is as follows:

> What is the best way to iterate and **modify** every element of an array using PHP 5?

These are the four choices listed in the link:

```
// method one
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) { 
    /* ... */ 
}

// method two
foreach($array as $key => &$val) { 
    /* ... */ 
}

// method three
foreach($array as $key => $val) { 
    /*... */ 
}

// method four
while(list($key, $val) = each($array)) { 
    /* ... */ 
}
```

The options 1, 3 and 4 are okay and they will work for iterating through the array. However, to modify the original array, you'll need to pass the `$val` by reference, which is what the second option does. That's why it's the preferred solution, in this case.

Comment: What about `array_walk`, `array_map`?

Comment: @deceze: I said -- "These are the four choices **listed in the link:**" -- sure, there are other ways, too :)

Comment: +1, thanks for clarifying about passing in the reference (`&`) .